# SQL Validation on insert - only allow one or another column to be populated

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation

I have a table that allows users to specify a tollerance by an absolute value or by a percentage

e.g. they could say +/- 1,000,000 
or 10%

so I have a table with a column for each value

What is th best way to ensure that only one or the other gets specified, not both

I will be adding validation to my UI, but would also like this checked by the database

Some kind of custom constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable WITH CHECK ADD
   CONSTRAINT CK_Mytable_ABSorPercent
          CHECK (ABSValue IS NULL OR PercentValue IS NULL)
```

This assumes your 2 columns are called `ABSValue` and `PercentValue` and both nullable. If they are nullable (they should be), change the check to your sentinel (N/A) value

Comment: possibly adding '.. AND (absvalue is not null OR percentvalue is not null)' to specify that one and only one must be set of the two.

Comment: thanks - I get the following whn applying that ALTER statement: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Mytable_ABSorPercent".

Comment: @Roonooir: you have a row with both values set... so it works! Run a SELECT with `WHERE NOT (ABSValue IS NULL OR PercentValue IS NULL)` to find the offending values

Answer (score 0):

This would vary depending on your choice of querying but it comes down to this:

If yourtable.percentage (column1) is not null then you cant set yourtable.value (column2)
you have to validate, check if column value=null and only then insert the value into the other column.

a simple sql command for this:

```
SELECT CASE <column1> WHEN = NULL      THEN column2
                      when <> NULL     then column1
```

this is only applicable if you make sure to validate right from the start,the query returns which column to update with your value